Assembly Calls Itself
I am rather new to assembly and have been trying to understand what is happening with the call instruction within this code. I have this simple C++ program that I compiled and disassembled with gdb.
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
  int number, i, a, x;
  
  for (a = 1; a <= 9; a++)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++){ 
          x = a * i;
          cout << a << " * " << i << " = " << x << endl;
        }
     }
  return 0;
}

Here is the disassembled code:
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000000000 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000000001 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000000004 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000000008 <+8>:     movl   $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x000000000000000f <+15>:    cmpl   $0x9,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000000013 <+19>:    jg     0xa3 <main+163>
   0x0000000000000019 <+25>:    movl   $0x1,-0xc(%rbp)
   0x0000000000000020 <+32>:    cmpl   $0x9,-0xc(%rbp)
   0x0000000000000024 <+36>:    jg     0x9a <main+154>
   0x0000000000000026 <+38>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000000029 <+41>:    imul   -0xc(%rbp),%eax
   0x000000000000002d <+45>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000000030 <+48>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000000033 <+51>:    mov    %eax,%esi
   0x0000000000000035 <+53>:    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 0x3c <main+60>
   0x000000000000003c <+60>:    callq  0x41 <main+65>
   0x0000000000000041 <+65>:    lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 0x48 <main+72>
   0x0000000000000048 <+72>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000000004b <+75>:    callq  0x50 <main+80>
   0x0000000000000050 <+80>:    mov    %rax,%rdx
   0x0000000000000053 <+83>:    mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000000056 <+86>:    mov    %eax,%esi
   0x0000000000000058 <+88>:    mov    %rdx,%rdi
   0x000000000000005b <+91>:    callq  0x60 <main+96>
   0x0000000000000060 <+96>:    lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 0x67 <main+103>
   0x0000000000000067 <+103>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000000006a <+106>:   callq  0x6f <main+111>
   0x000000000000006f <+111>:   mov    %rax,%rdx
   0x0000000000000072 <+114>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000000075 <+117>:   mov    %eax,%esi
   0x0000000000000077 <+119>:   mov    %rdx,%rdi
   0x000000000000007a <+122>:   callq  0x7f <main+127>
   0x000000000000007f <+127>:   mov    %rax,%rdx
   0x0000000000000082 <+130>:   mov    0x0(%rip),%rax        # 0x89 <main+137>
   0x0000000000000089 <+137>:   mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x000000000000008c <+140>:   mov    %rdx,%rdi
   0x000000000000008f <+143>:   callq  0x94 <main+148>
   0x0000000000000094 <+148>:   addl   $0x1,-0xc(%rbp)
   0x0000000000000098 <+152>:   jmp    0x20 <main+32>
   0x000000000000009a <+154>:   addl   $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x000000000000009e <+158>:   jmpq   0xf <main+15>
   0x00000000000000a3 <+163>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000000000a8 <+168>:   leaveq 
   0x00000000000000a9 <+169>:   retq   
End of assembler dump.

My main confusion are the call instructions that are pointing to the next line of code. It seems like the code is formatting the cout stream, however I don't see any call to cout in this function and I don't fully understand how it is even formatting the stream to begin with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

You don't see cout << aa and the following? Yes, these are calls. To the overloaded << operator. Note how the number of callq instructions matches the number of usages of << operators.

Can't reproduce.  Here the calls go to reasonable addresses, and gdb annotates them with the name of the called function, which is indeed the appropriate operator<< overload in each case.  If you set print asm-demangle on you will even see them in demangled human-readable form.

Can you show the commands you're using to compile and debug the program, as well as versions of gcc and gdb?

Are you by any chance running the debugger on the .o file (result of gcc -c) rather than the actual linked executable?  That would have this effect.  The .o file puts a zero in the displacement field of the call instruction, so it appears to go to the next instruction, but elsewhere in the file are relocation entries telling the linker what should actually go there in the executable.  Tools like objdump --disassemble --reloc can annotate the disassembly with that information, but gdb won't, probably because debugging a .o file is not really meaningful in the first place.

@NateEldredge: Yeah, that's for sure what's going on.  The LEA RIP-relative offsets are also 0, like lea 0x0(%rip),%rdi which is passing the address of std::cout, or others for strings.  I didn't know you could run GDB on a non-linked .o, but it's not useful.
